# Where to place hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

My project is like this:

```
/src/main/java
     -thegamers
         -app.java
         -hibernateutil.java
```

can someone tell me where to put the hibernate.cfg.xml?

because I'm getting this error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at thegamers.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at thegamers.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at thegamers.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2149)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2130)
    at thegamers.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: If you are getting the same error, even though it is placed under `/src`, Then You are going to check artifact(output) folder to make sure it is located under WEB-INF/classes after compiling.

Comment: `/src` is source folder? sometimes `/src/main/class` may stay as a source folder, then you place in `/src/main/class`

Comment: stupid question but how is something like org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration referred to by programmers? Is this the project path of the class Configuration?

Comment: Similar: [*Location of hibernate.cfg.xml in project?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18736594/642706)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**The config file `hibernate.cfg.xml` needs to be on the `classpath`.**

This can be accomplished in different ways, depending on your project.

- For a **web-app WAR** project (you are running the program in a Servlet container):
  placing it in `WEB-INF/classes` will work as files in `WEB-INF/classes` are visible on the classpath when app is running in container.
- For a **Maven**-style project (not running the program in a Servlet container): placing it in `/src/main/resources/` will work
- For otherwise, try in the `src/` directory.

Comment: I have a ant-file which builds me a jar file that I can deploy and it works fine. But if I try to load `new Configuration().configure("file:hibernate.cfg.xml");` it fails everytime doen't matter in which directory I placed hibernate.cfg.xml. If I printout the classpath via URLClassLoader I get `/opt/novell/teaming/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar ` which resides on the server-machine.

Comment: @StellaMaris so have you tried `new Configuration().configure("file:/opt/novell/teaming/apache-tomcat/path/to/hibernate.cfg.xml")`. You need to know where the file is when it's deployed/running to be able to access it that way

Answer (score 17):

I'm using maven, and it didn't work for me until I put hibernate.cfg.xml in `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 12):

At the root of your project: `/src` (at leat as default)

How to know if `/src` is the sources dir?
When you create a new Java class, it is contained in a package (normally it is called as the same name of the dir where it is created). So, in your class declarion you can see something like this:

```
package foo;

class MyClass{
```

In default IDE settings, the class should found under `/src/foo/MyClass.java`. As you can see, in this scenario `/src` acts as root sources dir.

Comment: is `/src` the dir of your sources project? I suggest to `rebuild` your project. The IDE can help you with this task.

Comment: how can i know this if /src is the dir of my project?

Comment: in eclipse, i created a source folder and put all conf files in it, its working now

Comment: @Noor, if your are not dealing so much with this tools, the IDE can help you at least in these kinds of problems because they can rebuild, reorganize, and clear several project configs :)

Answer (score 4):

if it is not web project  then do explicitly like that

```
new Configuration().configure( "pth/to/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildsessionfactory()
```

Hope this may help

@SiB pointed a link(mkyong's web site). It is explained well there.

Comment: If my `hibernat.cfg.xml` is in `/Hibernate/src/kasun/hibernate/testing/hibernate.cfg.xml` where `Hibernate` is the project and `kasun.hibernate.testing` is the package. How I specify the `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the above code

Answer (score 2):

The file is suppose to go into the root of your `/src` dir, while `/src` is not deployed, everything in it is built/copied out to `WEB-INF/classes` which IS deployed. Hibernate needs the `cfg.xml` file in the `classpath` of your project to load its config settings, your `WEB-INF` dir is not in your `classpath`, so if you were to put it there, you'd be **hiding** it from Hibernate and it wouldn't work.

This [thread](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-load-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-different-directory/) would tell you how to load the hibernate.cfg.xml from any different path.

Comment: `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib` WILL be on the classpath, when the WAR is deployed/exploded

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source. You can add the new folder where you placed the file, or move the file to the existing folder.

Answer (score 1):

Place `hibernate.cfg.xml` under `src/` folder or explicitly mention the path in code as:

```
new Configuration.configure("path of hibernate.cfg.xml").buildsessionfactory()
```

Answer (score 0):

CMD+N/CTR+N while you are on Eclips, it will open a dialog-box there you have to dubbel click on the Hibernate folder.
It will open a list of files with the XML extenuation.
Select the cfg.xml and click on continue and when you are done! click on finish. Eclips will now add the Class name with the cfg.xml file and show it under the SRC folder. GB

Answer (score -1):

try to place it into "`src/main/resources`" directory.