# Location of hibernate.cfg.xml in project?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I created a project with following structure:

[image]

HibernateUtil:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration  configuration = new Configuration().configure( "C:\\Users\\Nikolay_Tkachev\\workspace\\hiberTest\\src\\logic\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

at line

```
Configuration  configuration = new Configuration().configure( "C:\\Users\\Nikolay_Tkachev\\workspace\\hiberTest\\src\\logic\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

I have error

> Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\hiberTest\src\logic\hibernate.cfg.xml
>   not found Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   logic.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)    at
>   logic.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:9)    at
>   logic.Main.main(Main.java:12) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\hiberTest\src\logic\hibernate.cfg.xml
>   not found     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1947)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1928)
>     at logic.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
>     ... 2 more

What is the reason for the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Similar: [*Where to place hibernate.cfg.xml?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12677783/642706)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Give the path relative to your project.

Create a folder called `resources` in your  `src`  and put your config file there.

```
   configuration.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

And If you check your code

```
Configuration  configuration = new Configuration().configure( "C:\\Users\\Nikolay_Tkachev\\workspace\\hiberTest\\src\\logic\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

In two lines you are creating two configuration objects.

That should  work(haven't tested) if you write,

```
Configuration  configuration = new Configuration().configure( "C:\\Users\\Nikolay_Tkachev\\workspace\\hiberTest\\src\\logic\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
return  configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

But It fails after you deploy on the server,Since you are using system path than project relative path.

Comment: No need.But a good practice to put resources of project in `resources` folder :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - In `eclipse`, my simple code was working fine when the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file was inside the src folder. When I created a `resources` folder inside `src` and put the file there, my code threw an exception saying that it could not find the file anymore. How do I fix this problem ?

Comment: `config.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");` This does not work for me. I still get the error.

Answer (score 13):

Somehow placing under "src" folder didn't work for me.

Instead placing cfg.xml as below:

```
[Project Folder]\src\main\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml
```

worked.
Using this code

```
new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
```

in a file under

```
    [Project Folder]/src/main/java/com/abc/xyz/filename.java
```

In addition have this piece of code in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<mapping resource="hibernate/Address.hbm.xml" />
<mapping resource="hibernate/Person.hbm.xml" />
```

Placed the above hbm.xml files under:

EDIT:

```
[Project Folder]/src/main/resources/hibernate/Address.hbm.xml
[Project Folder]/src/main/resources/hibernate/Person.hbm.xml
```

Above structure worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can put the file "hibernate.cfg.xml" to the src folder (src\hibernate.cfg.xml) and then init the config as the code below:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();          
sessionFactory =configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an reality example when customize folder structure:
Folder structure, and initialize class `HibernateUtil`
[image]

with:

```
return new Configuration().configure("/config/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

mapping:
[image]

with customize entities mapping files:

```
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.vy.entities.Users"/>
        <mapping class="com.vy.entities.Post"/>
        <mapping resource="config/Users.hbm.xml"/>      
        <mapping resource="config/Post.hbm.xml"/>               
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

(Note: Simplest way, if you follow default way, it means put all xml config files inside `src` folder, when build sessionFactory, only:

```
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested: if you are using **Intellj**, just simply put `hibernate.cfg.xml` under `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 2):

try below code it will solve your problem.

```
Configuration  configuration = new Configuration().configure("/logic/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that i had a exculding patern in the resorces folder.
After removing it the

```
config.configure();
```

worked for me. With the structure 
src/java/...HibernateUtil.java and cfg file under src/resources.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason why this exception occurs is if you call the configure method twice on a `Configuration` or `AnnotatedConfiguration` object like this -

```
AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
config.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass.class);
//Use this if config files are in src folder
config.configure();
//Use this if config files are in a subfolder of src, such as "resources"
config.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Btw, this project structure is inside eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Using configure() method two times is responsible the problem for me. Instead of using like this :

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    configuration.configure("/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Now, I am using like this, problem does not exist anymore.

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

P.S: My hibernate.cfg.xml file is located at "src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml",too.
The code belove works for me. at hibernate-5

```
public class HibernateUtil {

 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory ;


 static {
     try{
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
 }
     catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a Maven Project, create a folder named resources under src/main folder and add the resources folder as a source folder in your classpath.

You can do that by going to Configure Build Path and then clicking Add Folder to the Sources Tab.

Then check the resources folder and click Apply.

Then just use :

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```