# Unable to run basic hibernate 5 program

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to run the program given in hibernate tutorial([basic](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-test)).But I am facing error.  Surprisingly, there are very few error logs displayed in the console. If anyone can show me where I am going wrong, I will be grateful. I have spent lot of time trying to resolve it before posting it here.
Below is my code;

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hr</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hr</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/hbm/Event.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Event.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="org.hibernate.tutorial.hbm">
    <class name="Event" table="EVENTS">
        <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE"/>
        <property name="title"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Test class : NativeApiIllustrationTest

```
package org.hibernate.tutorial.hbm;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class NativeApiIllustrationTest extends TestCase {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if ( sessionFactory != null ) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testBasicUsage() {
        // create a couple of events...
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save( new Event( "Our very first event!", new Date() ) );
        session.save( new Event( "A follow up event", new Date() ) );
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        // now lets pull events from the database and list them
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List result = session.createQuery( "from Event" ).list();
        for ( Event event : (List<Event>) result ) {
            System.out.println( "Event (" + event.getDate() + ") : " + event.getTitle() );
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Logs in console :

```
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:51 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:51 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE]
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=fod, password=****}
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Jun 13, 2017 6:54:52 AM org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl stopService
INFO: HHH000369: Error stopping service [class org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Null pointer is coming at line : Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();   It indicates that sessionFactory is null.

Below are the jars I have added in the classpath
I [image: Jars added in the class path]

Comment: The answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736594/location-of-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-project) question might help; but I recommend you to learn the new way because that way of configuring the application is obsolete IMHO :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to the hibernate.cfg.xml and it started working.The modified xml is as below :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hr</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hr</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>     
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/hbm/Event.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The change I done in this xml is modifying the connection url :

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
```