# Error: hibernate.properties not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I receive an error. I'll be glad if you help me. I got the following error message while studying hibernate. I also using PostgreSQL database. I did it by following [that video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2F1zCAf_NU&index=3&list=PL4AFF701184976B25).

**Error message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
```

[image]

> HibernateTest.java (main class)

```
package hibernate1;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("oguzhancevik");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

> UserDetails.Java
>   [image]
>
> hibernate.cfg.xml
>   [image]

Comment: show hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location of hibernate.cfg.xml in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736594/location-of-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-project)

Comment: Need to see the hibernate.cfg file

Comment: @PeterHaddad i added others.

Comment: @sharon182 i added it

Comment: @clinomaniac a little different. I tried but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (right answer).

Source https://github.com/oguzhancevik/Hibernate

> Hibernate Configuration File
>
> > hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Set the current session context -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

</session-factory>
```

> Entity Class
>
> > Student.java

```
package com.oguzhancevik.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

> Main Class
>
> > CreateStudentDemo.java

```
package com.oguzhancevik.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.oguzhancevik.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {

            // use the session object to save Java object
            System.out.println("Creating new Student object...");
            Student student = new Student("Oguzhan", "Cevik", "cevik.ogsan@gmail.com");

            // start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            // save the student object
            System.out.println("Saving the student...");
            session.save(student);

            // commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Done!");

        } finally {
            session.close();
            factory.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its Main.java, you need to instantiate configuration.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(); conf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

And start session fron conf object

Comment: Nothing has changed. I'm getting the same error again

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null

Comment: I saw. I tried but unfortunaletly nothing has changed.

Comment: @Oguzhan Cevik 
please show line 0 in your xml cfg file

Comment: `<!-- ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java ~ ~ License: 
 GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later. ~ See the 
 lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>. -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>`

Comment: there are people who say hibernate 5 version is troubled on the internet.

Comment: @OguzhanCevik delete the first comment in the xml file , and if the error still occurs replace this line : "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dt‌​d" with this line  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"