# HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

Working on my servlet I had this problem:

[image: IDE tree view]

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2093)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2074)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
    com.dede.app1st.controller.AddUser.doPost(AddUser.java:26)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

What is the reason for the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please update the title with a description of the problem so it is easier for people to find your question and help you.

Comment: It appears to be looking for a configuration file in the root directory and it's not there. I think there's a bad path somewhere in your setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location of hibernate.cfg.xml in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736594/location-of-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-project)

Comment: thanks for the title :) but I do not think the problem is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hibernate.cfg.xml seems to be searched in your classpath root, but is located in the subpackage `com.dede.app1st.controller`. Moving it to the root package should fix the problem.