# Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number -1

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jdbc, xsd

I want to create just a simple java program using hibernate . I have created a maven project for that .

I have created two files one is hibernate configuration file and the other is app.java file .

Both the files are below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "https://www.hibernate-org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <properties name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</properties>
    <properties name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber</properties>
    <properties name="connection.username">root</properties>
    <properties name="connection.password">root</properties>
    <properties name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</properties>
    <properties name="hbm2ddl">update</properties>
    <properties name="show_sql">true</properties> 
  </session-factory>    
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
package com.tutorial.MavenProject;



import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Project World!" );
        SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        
        /*Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();*/
        
        System.out.println(factory);
        System.out.println(factory.isClosed());
    }
}
```

And this is my app.java file.

Now when I build and run my app.java I am getting an exception like this . I am a beginner in hibernate so don't know how I can solve this problem .

```
Project World!
May 01, 2021 2:45:43 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.31.Final
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number -1 and column -1 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":properties}'. One of '{"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":property, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":mapping, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":class-cache, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":collection-cache, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":event, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":listener}' is expected.
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at com.tutorial.MavenProject.App.main(App.java:16)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":properties}'. One of '{"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":property, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":mapping, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":class-cache, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":collection-cache, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":event, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":listener}' is expected.]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:463)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:127)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":properties}'. One of '{"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":property, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":mapping, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":class-cache, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":collection-cache, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":event, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg":listener}' is expected.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:511)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3587)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1971)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:101)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleStartElement(StAXEventConnector.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge(StAXEventConnector.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:460)
    ... 7 more
```

I don't know what mistake I am doing here .

Comment: looks like instead of `properties` you need to use `property`

Comment: does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736594/location-of-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-project