# I am getting error in: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting this Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse      configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
at com.jwt.hibernate.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:13)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
```

My hibernate.cfg file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3006/mydb</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
<property  name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
<mapping resource="com/jwt/hibernate/student.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Mapping File is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.jwt.hibernate.Student" table="STUDENT">
<id column="ID" name="id" type="int" />
<property column="STUDENT_NAME" name="name" type="string" />
<property column="DEGREE" name="degree" type="string" />
<property column="ROLL" name="roll" type="string" />
<property column="PHONE" name="phone" type="string" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My Bean class is:

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String degree;
    private String roll;
    private String phone;
    /** Getters and setters omitted **/
}
```

My Tester class is:

```
public class SimpleTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("Gourab");
    student.setRoll("101");
    student.setPhone("8888");
    student.setDegree("B.E");

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(student);
    System.out.println("Object saved successfully.....!!");
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    factory.close();
  }
}
```

[My Folder Structure is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT6yC.png)

I have added all required jars for connecting to hibernate and mysql(e.g hibernate-core 3.8.9.Final.jar,mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar)
But still I am getting the error.
Please Help me out.
Thanks in advance

Full Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse    configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
at com.jwt.hibernate.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:12)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
... 2 more
```

[My jar files are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bwAq.png)

Comment: try to find out if `hibernate.cfg.xml` is placed in the correct directory.

Comment: My hibernate.cfg.xml file is placed in src folder.It is outside of any package @ulrich

Comment: This seems to be the wrong place... look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12677783/1988304) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18736594/1988304)

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich for help.But I have tried after changing the path also.It is not working.

Comment: please update your question and show the locations you have tried. What is the content of this method call: `cfg.configure("...path.../hibernate.cfg.xml");` ?

Comment: add full stack trace. Also how is this related to Spring?

Comment: I have uploaded one snapshot of the folder structure@Ulrich..Please check it once.

Comment: You said you changed the folder of `hibernate.cfg.xml` , but the image shows it is still located in `src` . Look at the links to the questions I've posted in my 2. comment

Comment: As you told,I created a resources folder and pasted my hibernate.cfg.xml file in that folder and also I have changed the code in SimpleTest class to cfg.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml"). But it didn't work.It is giving the same error. @Ulrich

Comment: oh no, no ... now you mix up maven build structure and eclipse conventions. I can't give an introduction into maven here ...

Comment: I don't follow this question anymore. I've flagged it as a duplicate

Comment: I didn't use any maven structure.@Ulrich

Comment: @Ulrich Having `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the root of `src` folder is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to check **your** `.jar` again? I try to execute your project `SimpleTest.java` with my `.jar`. It is work. Please take a look

[image: hibernate]

Comment: You have `hibernate3.jar` in the class path.

Comment: I have hibernate3.jar in my classpath.Thanks for your help @v.ladynev

Comment: @GourabSarkar Does everything work now? Did you have `hibernate-core-xxx.jar` and  `hibernate3.jar`, or you just replace `hibernate-core-xxx.jar` with  `hibernate3.jar`?

Comment: @v.ladynev I have both jars hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final jar and hibernate3 jar.But Still Same problem.

Comment: @GourabSarkar You need to delete `hibernate3.jar` of course.

Comment: Yes.Now I have deleted hibernate3.jar as you said.Still same error@v.ladynev

Comment: @GourabSarkar Delete all jars, and get somewhere a valid set of jars for Hibernate 3.6.9. For an example here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.9.Final

Comment: @v.ladynev I have added my jars with this question.Please find it and tell me what changes I have to make

Answer (score 0):

I copied every file from your page as above and created a new project. Please follow the below structure to avoid the above exception.

[image: Project Structure to place hibernate cfg file]

```
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println("Maven + Hibernate + MySQL");
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    Student st1 = new Student();

    st1.setName("srinivas");
    st1.setPhone("99");
    st1.setRoll("123");


    session.save(st1);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
}
```

Comment: you provide a solution for maven, but Gourab uses pure Eclipse

Comment: I think we can still follow the same structure and try for a normal Java project in Eclipse.

Comment: for learning, it's not good to mix up to concepts. I don't follow this question anymore

Comment: Could you please give me a solution for simple java project.It will be helpful for me.Here I am not understanding what is App.java@srinivas

Comment: It is just a main class to try for insertion of Student DB and to call session factory of Hibernate Util. Create the resources folder as same in the picture and try to use this App.java below for inserting.

`public class App 
{
 public static void main( String[] args )
 {
  System.out.println("Maven + Hibernate + MySQL");
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

  session.beginTransaction();
  Student st1 = new Student();

  st1.setName("srinivas");
  st1.setPhone("99");
  st1.setRoll("123");


  session.save(st1);
  session.getTransaction().commit();
 }
}`

Comment: _I think we can still follow the same structure and try for a normal Java project in Eclipse._ It is incorrect. Because of Maven builder adds `src/main/resources` to the class path.

Comment: Please, add your example to the answer :)

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the problem in using normal java project and what is the mistake here I did.@srinivas @v.ladynev

Comment: @GourabSarkar You can use normal Java project. It is correct :)

Comment: But still I am getting the same error.Could you please tell me the reason.where I am doing mistake @ v.ladynev

Comment: @GourabSarkar Please, add full stack trace to your question :)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
 at com.jwt.hibernate.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:12)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
 at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
 ... 2 more

Comment: Now I have added hibernate.cfg file in resources folder.

Comment: @GourabSarkar To your question! And full.

Comment: Can You post the SimpleTest.java once. @GourabSarkar

Comment: @GourabSarkar Hibernate can find `hibernate.cfg.xml` but can't parse it :)

Comment: Try this , download hibernate-core jar from maven repository and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate can't parse your `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

`hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar` has a file with DTD `hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final/org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`

Check this file inside `hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar`.

You need to have the same `DTD` as `hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd` has.

`<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">`

Looks like you already have it.

May be you have other `hibernate-core` jar in the class path with other DTD.

Comment: I have changed the doctype.Now also Its not working.I am working with hibernate-core 3.8.9.Final.jar.Is it fine ??????@v.ladynav

Comment: @GourabSarkar I think it is fine if you use corresponding versions of other jars. What the stack trace with new `DOCTYPE`?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
 at com.jwt.hibernate.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:12)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.sourceforge.net Nested exception: hibernate.sourceforge.net
 at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)

Comment: No changes in stack trace.@v.ladynev

Comment: @GourabSarkar There is a change in the stack trace `www.hibernate.org` -> `hibernate.sourceforge.net`

Comment: oh.Sorry I didn't notice.@v.ladynev

Comment: @GourabSarkar Sorry I was mistaken. You had the correct DTD. I update my post with some thought.

Comment: @GourabSarkar Try to use Hibernate 4 or Hibernate 5