# hibernate.cfg.xml in source file and still not found

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have hibernate.cfg.xml file inside my src file and I'm still getting this error. Please see my HibernateUtil class, errors and xml file.
I tried most of solutions that other people posted in other treads.

Here is the screenshot of the structure:
[image]

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HiberUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        //        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
//        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
//                applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
//        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Aug 06, 2017 10:40:29 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Aug 06, 2017 10:40:29 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Aug 06, 2017 10:40:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 06, 2017 10:40:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Aug 06, 2017 10:40:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 06, 2017 10:40:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Here is the hibernate.cfg.xml if you need this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cokolada</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>        
        <!-- Mapiranje klasa -->
        <mapping class="model.Cokolada"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: you mean hibernate.cfg.xml? I just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it would be helpful to know **what, exactly** you've tried from other threads in order to be able to rule stuff out and help diagnose your problem.

Second, it cannot find your file because it isn't located in the proper place to be found. **It needs to be in your classpath**. I use maven and its required to be in here:
src/main/resources

[Check out this SO post, he gives the best answer here I think.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29352557/6560068)

> It is the same for any other time you need a file visible on the classpath. The config file hibernate.cfg.xml needs to be on the classpath. Exactly that and nothing else is key. This can be accomplished in different ways, depending on your project... [follow link and upvote the other guy for the full answer]