# Where to put hibernate config file

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This is my hibernate config file. I put it in src/main/resources and I put it in src .

But all the time I get this error:

**Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is how I wrote my config file. I am using spring. I just found out that actually all this is not necessary in spring. You could just autowire SessionFactory.

Comment: Is the file named `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: yes  hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: is it a spring boot project? And which Spring and Hibernate version?

Comment: Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677783/where-to-place-hibernate-cfg-xml

Comment: I am using Spring Framework 4.3.3 and Hibernate 5 . The project was setup a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can place:
hibernate.cfg.xml file to

```
src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

or persistence.xml file to

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

If you are using Hibernate's proprietary API, you'll need the hibernate.cfg.xml. If you are using JPA i.e. Hibernate EntityManager, you'll need the persistence.xml.